Conditionals in Asymptote
I was reading the Asymptote doc about arithmetic and logical operators: https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Arithmetic-_0026-logical.html.
How can I make a basic if elseif else statement in Asymptote? Alternatively, what resource can I consult to learn this?
This is a M(non)WE:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    real t = 1;
    real f = 2;
    if (t==1 && f>0) {
        draw((0,0) -- (0,1));
    }
    else {
        draw((0,0) -- (1,0));
    }
\end{asy}
\end{document}


This seems to work for me:
with f negative ...
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
real t=1.0;
real f=-2;
if(t==1 && f>0) {
  draw((0,0) -- (1,0));
} else {
  draw((0,0) -- (0,1));
}
\end{asy}

\end{document}


with f positive ...
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
real t=1.0;
real f=2;
if(t==1 && f>0) {
  draw((0,0) -- (1,0));
} else {
  draw((0,0) -- (0,1));
}
\end{asy}

\end{document}



Weird! It was terminating with an error earlier, but now it is running fine. This thread is useful for seeing the syntax though. Merry Christmas, by the way.

@Jasper Happy Boxing Day :-).
